# How to Export Into Movie - Ragdoll Scene (Falling Maniquin)

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to figure out how to export into a movie a scene wherein a manequin falls into the ground. I can preview the animation thru BLENDER GAME engine but I have no clue how to export the movie as a scene itself.

Thanks

Comment: it sounds like you just need to render the animation with a transparent back ground and then overlay the result on top of your existing movie.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I can play the animation thru BLENDER GAME ENGINE but I cannot find any way of exporting that into a movie ?

Comment: I am interpreting our use of "Movie" to mean a video already in existence, most likely outside of blender. "Scene" to mean a blender scene, each blender file can have multiple scenes. "Maniquin/Ragdoll" to mean a physics based mesh/rig in Blender. The bit that is confusing me is the Blender Game Engine. Does the physics simulation work outside the game engine? Why are you using the game engine? The built in physics simulator should handle everything you need if you are not constructing a interactive game.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to recreate what was created in this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOEO1qLszCw

and it uses the BLENDER RENDER engine to create the effect of RAGDOLLING. Now back to my question, how do I export the animation as a movie from this BLENDER ENGINE and not the CYCLES RENDER?

Comment: relevant https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48976/export-video-from-game-engine-scene there were also some notes about using a screen capture program to record the whole screen, but the link is dead.

Comment: yes, i used a SCREEN CAPTURE app to get the vid because I have no clue how to export the animation in BLENDER ENGINE

Comment: i still can't find a solution to this.....or is what I think not possible at all?

Comment: I think the point is it is not designed to be recorded. Can you rethink your approach to not use the Game engine?